# how to ADD a NEW entity/item/effect to Minecraft Java

Tags: minecraft-modding

In Minecraft Java, I am creating many resource packs by myself (no studio or external resource) so, I want to ***ADD*** a new file/entity/element/items/etc. to the game to not replace an old item because EVERY item/effect/entity has SOME use in the game. In conclusion: how I can ADD [not replace] a file in the game and give it custom physical and mental properties?

Comment: In future, please edit your existing question instead of posting a new one about the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get a texture for the Minecraft mob (or make one yourself).
2. In [MCreator](https://mcreator.net/), Click on "New Mod"
3. Next, click on "Mob" and name your mod. Names mustn't repeat. Make it something you understand, the end-user won't see this name.
4. Then, fill out all of the custom characteristics of your mob.
5. Finally, export your mod into your preferred version of Minecraft.

I found these instructions from [here](https://mcreator.net/wiki/how-make-mob).

Comment: Thanks for informing me. however, everyone is in 1.16.5 (probably). MCreator is set back a year and a half [1.15.2]